# Type inference error while pattern matching

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types, gadt

In the below code I keep getting this error — `pattern type is incompatible with expected type;` Which I feel is incorrect. Is this a possible bug in Scala 2? Anywhere I can read more about it?

```scala
    sealed trait Foo[A] { self =>
      def eval: Option[A] =
        self match {
          case Foo.Number => Option(1)
          case Foo.Text   => Option("Ok")
        }
    }
    
    object Foo {
      case object Number extends Foo[Int]
      case object Text extends Foo[String]
    }
    
    println("ok!")
```

Weirdly it works when `eval` is implemented in the companion object `Foo`

Comment: Yeah this is a bug AFAIK, I think it also works in **Scala 3**

Comment: Yeah, it works in Scala 3. However I couldn't find the right bug pointing to this issue.

Comment: @tusharmath https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11510

Comment: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen++gadt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072185/understanding-the-limits-of-scala-gadt-support