# (Scala 2.12.8) pattern type is incompatible with expected type for parameterized type inside of parameterized class

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching, gadt, scala-2.12

(Scala 2.12.8)
[Full Example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZRgn8N17RmSmpi4b78Zr5Q)

So lets say you have some "TypeEvidence" for some specific concrete types:

```
sealed trait TypeEvidence[+T]
object TypeEvidence{
  case object DoubleType extends TypeEvidence[Double]
  case object LongType extends TypeEvidence[Long]
  case object StringType extends TypeEvidence[String]
}
```

I can match on those evidence objects like this:

```
object ThisIsOk{
  def apply[T](ev: TypeEvidence[T]): Option[T] = {
    ev match {
      case TypeEvidence.DoubleType => Some(123.456)
      case TypeEvidence.LongType => Some(1234L)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

But not like this:

```
class ThisFails[T]{
  def apply(ev: TypeEvidence[T]): Option[T] = {
    ev match {
      case TypeEvidence.DoubleType => Some(123.456)
      case TypeEvidence.LongType => Some(1234L)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

This fails to compile with:

```
pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : TypeEvidence.DoubleType.type
 required: TypeEvidence[T]
pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : TypeEvidence.LongType.type
 required: TypeEvidence[T]
```

Why is this? And how can this be worked around?

Comment: fwiw, it compiles in Scala 3.2.0. In general, Scala 3 is a lot better at GADTs than Scala 2 is. (I don't know what specific improvements might be in play here.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544070 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359696 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072185 https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5195

Comment: We know. Unfortunately progressing to scala 3 is not an option at this time.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this with a type class?

```
class ThisFails[T]{
  def apply(ev: TypeEvidence[T])(implicit 
    teto: TypeEvidenceToOption[T]
  ): Option[T] = teto(ev)
}

trait TypeEvidenceToOption[T] {
  def apply(ev: TypeEvidence[T]): Option[T]
}
object TypeEvidenceToOption {
  implicit val double: TypeEvidenceToOption[Double] = 
    { case TypeEvidence.DoubleType => Some(123.456) }
  implicit val long: TypeEvidenceToOption[Long] = 
    { case TypeEvidence.LongType => Some(1234L) }
  implicit def default[T]: TypeEvidenceToOption[T] = _ => None
}

new ThisFails[Double].apply(TypeEvidence.DoubleType) // Some(123.456)
new ThisFails[Long].apply(TypeEvidence.LongType) // Some(1234)
new ThisFails[String].apply(TypeEvidence.StringType) // None
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why it didn't work the way you expected. The only reasonable explanation I tell to myself is that the compiler has no issue using `T` as a placeholder for any type while `T` belongs to the parameterized method, whereas when it belongs to a parameterized class, it's more restrictive in terms of what you can do with it.

As a workaround, you can use `.type` and `.asIstanceOf`:

```
  class ThisFails[T] {
    def apply(ev: TypeEvidence[T]): Option[T] = {
      ev match {
        case _: TypeEvidence.DoubleType.type => Some(123.456.asInstanceOf[T])
        case _: TypeEvidence.LongType.type   => Some(1234L.asInstanceOf[T])
        case _                               => None
      }
    }
  }

  val x  = new ThisFails[Long]
  val x2 = new ThisFails[Double]
  val x3 = new ThisFails[String]

  println(x.apply(TypeEvidence.LongType))    // Some(1234)
  println(x2.apply(TypeEvidence.DoubleType)) // Some(123.456)
  println(x3.apply(TypeEvidence.StringType)) // None
```

I'm aware it's not nice, but you asked for a workaround. This pattern match now matches *an object* of the given *type*. Of course, with this workaround, having the objects "caseable" is redundant now.

I had a peek at the disassembled code of `object ThisIsOk` to figure out this workaround:

```
public static class ThisIsOk$
{
    public static final ThisIsOk$ MODULE$;
    
    static {
        ThisIsOk$.MODULE$ = new ThisIsOk$();
    }

    public <T> Option<T> apply(final Main.TypeEvidence<T> ev) {
        Object module$;
        if (Main.TypeEvidence$.DoubleType$.MODULE$.equals(ev)) {
            module$ = new Some((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble(123.456));
        }
        else if (Main.TypeEvidence$.LongType$.MODULE$.equals(ev)) {
            module$ = new Some((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToLong(1234L));
        }
        else {
            module$ = None$.MODULE$;
        }
        return (Option<T>)module$;
    }
}
```

I saw here the way pattern match works is by calling `equals` on their types, but since `equals` is not overridden, what this actually does is a reference check. Recall:

```
// in Object.java file:
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Also I saw a cast to `Option<T>` in the end.
So with these observations, the class `ThisFails[T]` workaround I just showed earlier gets disassembled into this:

```
public static class ThisFails<T>
{
    public Option<T> apply(final Main.TypeEvidence<T> ev) {
        Object module$;
        if (Main.TypeEvidence$.DoubleType$.MODULE$ == ev) {
            module$ = new Some((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble(123.456));
        }
        else if (Main.TypeEvidence$.LongType$.MODULE$ == ev) {
            module$ = new Some((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToLong(1234L));
        }
        else {
            module$ = None$.MODULE$;
        }
        return (Option<T>)module$;
    }
}
```

Which is almost identical to the `object ThisIsOk`'s disassembled code, except for using `==` instead of `equals`, which does not matter in this case, as I explained earlier.

I tested it with both Scala 2.13.8 and your version [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/owyyglJJRi6XofXIp6GH4w) on Scastie, and both worked.